# rerunning, restaring and aborting threads

Tags: multithreading

I need a suggestion - I'm writing an application that will work as kind of TaskScheduler and I want each task to be a separate Thread. I have a

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<Thread>
```

with my threads/tasks but - I can only start a thread **once** from this "Bag", once it is finished - I can't restart it again (it's a scheduler application so one thread may be launched once per day/hour/minute... every few seconds...). 
Should I create new Thread in my "Bag" each time a task is supposed to run? 
Also - I can't really remove objects from **ConcurrentBag** (?)
It would be easier with:

```
List<Thread>
```

... but I read List is not a good approach to multithreading.

One more thing - it will be required to kill tasks that take too long to finish. So I will need to do **Abort** on a thread - a thing I see people don't reccomend as well.

Does anyone have some tips for managing a list of threads/tasks as I described? thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind - I gave up with "threads" and will use separate "processes" instead.